# When I export plots from R to .eps all the vertex names disappear

Tags: r, plot, eps

When I export plots from R to .eps all the vertex names disappear. The plot and the title is fine but all the names every time disappear and I have to write them one by one.

[R Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOdXa.png)

[EPS file opened in Illustrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VBsG.png)

Comment: What function are you using to create the plot and what code are you using to save the plot? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: font problem? alpha-transparency problem?